# Deleting old records from DB using crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I have a table in my MySql DB called "user_action". I want to delete old records from this table that are older then 30 days (according to the "action_date" datetime column) on a daily basis and I want to do it using crontab.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Thought #1: How would you do it in SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `/usr/local/bin/clear-out-old-records.sh` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
SQL="DELETE FROM user_action WHERE action_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)"

MYSQL_USER="<your-user>"
MYSQL_PASS="<your-password>"
MYSQL_DB="<your-db>"

echo $SQL | /usr/bin/mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS $MYSQL_DB
```

...and then put `/usr/local/bin/clear-out-old-records.sh` into crontab.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Additional question: where does the standard mysql logging go to? (amount of records deleted for example)

Answer (score 2):

For authentication, create a `.my.cnf` file in the user's home directory:

```
[client]
user=username
password=password
```

Then create a file called `crontab`. I **strongly** recommend that you don't edit contab directly, but always through this one file; otherwise it's too easy to accidentally overwrite the contents of crontab.

```
MAILTO="email@foo.com"

# 1. minute (0-59)
# |   2. hour (0-23)
# |   |   3. day of month (1-31)
# |   |   |   4. month (1-12)
# |   |   |   |   5. day of week (0-7: 0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
# |   |   |   |   |   6. commandline
# |   |   |   |   |   |
#min hr  dom mon dow command
  0   3   *   *   *  mysql DATABASE -e "DELETE FROM user_action WHERE action_date < subdate(now(), interval 30 day)" >/dev/null
```

Replace DATABASE with the name of your database.

This means that the cleanup will run at 3:00 AM every night (every day of month, every day of week, etc). Errors will be sent to your email. `>/dev/null` is necessary to hide MySQL's non-error output, which you're usually not interested in.

And run this command to update the system's copy of crontab:

```
crontab ./crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a script in your favorite language that executes the following query:

Pseudocode:

```
"DELETE FROM user_action WHERE created_at < #{(Date.now - 30.days)}"
```

Then add this to cron to execute daily.

Answer (score -1):

Write a SQL (preferable stored procedure) to do that and execute that SQL via crontab.

Comment: How do I execute a stored procedure from a crontab?

Comment: use "mysql" command to execute procedure like any other SQL. You will need to specify Server/DB/Username/password on command line